# Hacer una función que retorne el numero de Registros de una tabla

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle, funciones, plsql, data

estoy aprendiendo funciones en ORACLE PL SQL y tengo un ejercicio en el cual me piden Hacer una función que retorne el número de Registros de la tabla VENDEDOR, lo que he intentado es hacer los siguiente:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION countRegistros
RETURN NUMBER @cantidadRegistros AS cantidadRegistros

BEGIN

SELECT @cantidadRegistros = count(*) from vendedor
RETURN @cantidadRegistros
END;


VARIABLE Numero_Registros NUMBER;
EXECUTE :Numero_Registros := countRegistros();
PRINT Numero_Registros
```

Pero a la hora de crear la función me aparece el siguiente error en el begin

[image: error]

Si alguien me puede ayudar a terminar este ejericicio estaria agradecido gracias.

Comment: Edite la pregunta porque La sintaxis no es de PL/SQL de Oracle o cambie las etiquetas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

vas encaminado pero te falta un poco.

Cuando creas una función en Oracle debes de indicar el tipo de dato que vas a devolver y devolverlo dentro de tu código.

Te dejo un link donde puedes revisar un poco más sobre el tema: [Link con información](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/oracleya/temarios/descripcion.php?cod=255)

De igual forma te detallo un poco como debería de ir tu consulta.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION countRegistros
RETURN number
IS
cantidadRegistros int :=0;
BEGIN
SELECT count(*) into cantidadRegistros from vendedor;
RETURN cantidadRegistros;
END
```

Comment: hola amigo, agrege el codigo que me pasastes pero ahora tengo un error que dice  en el begin, te lo coloco en la descripcion                                                                                                 
LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
3/1       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:     constant exception <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table columns long    double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national

Comment: Hola amigo, corregí el código un poco, anteriormente utilicé sintaxis propia de Sql Server y no de Oracle.

Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: vale, ya lo revise y si me sirvio gracias :)